# whole page moves a bit when a show function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build my first website www.angelosmavraidis.com
I have inserted a javascript to show 8 divs of the same class when clicking on the "artwork" div.
The problem is that when the "artwork" is clicked and the rest of the divs show up the whole page moves a bit to the left.
Anyone know why this is happening?

Also can you recommend a better alternative to the following script to do the job?

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.mainmenu').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('.artwork').eq(index).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any shifting.

Comment: is a scroll bar appearing on the browser window when the content is unhidden?

Comment: the shifting occurs when the artwork is clicked.

Comment: no scroll bar appearing if the zoom is fit

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault` here like

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.mainmenu').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $('.artwork').eq(index).show();
        });
    });
});
```